# Add dome-like sphere with Mapbox GL

Tags: mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

How can I add a 3 dimensional sphere to Mapbox GL using the Javascript API? I've read about the fill-extrusion property but I'm unsure how I would use it for a sphere. I'm trying to create a semi-transparent dome around a latitude/longitude coordinate based on a distance radius.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to do anything like that at present. The only 3D features are fill-extrusions, which have flat tops. Maybe you could create an image that looked like a 3D dome, and overlay that.

Comment: ...and here is an example of approximating a dome using fill-extrusions https://bl.ocks.org/andrewharvey/c1fdbebafe3fc46d743ba9514e4d64b2

Comment: Wow, that's crazy. But awesome. :)